How would people/vegetation on planet change with no sunlight getting through?
Building a world now where the sunlight is blocked, really none gets through.
Some Light comes from other sources but how would the people and vegetation change to adapt to this? Lets say it has been that way for hundreds of years
Thank you!

Quite obviously, the main change in people and vegetation would be that they would change from being alive to being dead. And it would take very much less that hundreds of years. Since apparently the question assumes that they are not dead, there needs to be some wondrous reason for that.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

How is energy from the sun reaching them? (or has it died? If so then where is the energy for life coming from?) .. no energy tends to equal no life, of any type .. what's available as a primary energy source for life is going to change any answer that isn't just "it will make everything dead", likely in some significant ways.

One important effect is the sunscreen industry would collapse

If the llight isn't reaching them, then how are they staying warm? Heat in our air occurs because sunlight hits the ground, then radiates upward. No sunlight means no heat. The planet would iceball in a period of months.

Hello @Nol. For future reference, we call this a high concept question and they're off-topic. Briefly, an HCQ introduces a small change (no light) and asked for enormous consequences (how would people/plants adapt?). They're notoriously too broad, opinion-based, hypothetical, and lead to all answers having equal value. Questions can be closed for Needs More Details, Needs More Focus, Opinion-Based, and Not About WB Per the [help]. On Stack Exchange, you need to be specific and objective.

The question says the light is BLOCKED.  That means there is some kind of an object around the planet, at about the equilibrium temperature of the planet (except for albedo).  The planet would be limited in how much heat it can radiate into space (everything is now effectively some distance underground) so it would actually heat up.

99% of larger Flora and Fauna die out within 3 months from the event
A 100% elimination of sunlight getting to the ground means that all surface plants die, as they can't photosynthesize. As a direct result, every surface-living herbivore animal will die out soon after they consume the last plants and starve within about 3 weeks. Most Carnivores will follow soon after consuming the last herbivores and their carcasses. I estimate about 3 months for those to be gone, leaving us with a food crisis.
Without a way to provide plants with light, above-earth civilizations will start to wither and die from starvation within less than a year as stockpiles are depleted. If there are any ways to provide light for plants, then these limit the area of plant growth, which in turn limits food production and thus the size of the civilization. But it will be extremely costly.
Underground civilizations that do not rely on any above-ground resources at all might have little to no problems adapting to the lack of any influx of new resources from above.
What's left...
After a couple of hundred years, the flora and fauna without a way to keep plants alive is bleak: The planet is left with mostly microorganisms, fungi (mushrooms), and cave-dwelling, underground civilizations that would have conquered the surface but for one thing: it's covered in inhospitable ice. Since the surface isn't warmed by the sun, almost all life will be underground, using the planet's heat as the main energy source to allow life.
Further Reading

Medieval ways to tell time, without a sun or stars


Those with nuclear power might possibly be expected to be able to keep 'some' alive with crops grown under artificial lighting for some time, if not indefinitely (for a given value of your indefinitely) 'if' they also have the means to mine fresh fuel, IF that is they organise themselves fast enough & have sufficient military might (& the strength of will to use it) to protect both themselves and their infrastructure from those trying to get it for themselves (until those have died) & prevent it's destruction during that early period of panic.

There's a whole lotta ifs and provisos there ^  .. and OP hasn't made clear what level of tech he has, so it may all be moot anyway.
